# How to do a maven install without test scope jars

Tags: java, maven, heroku

The application is written in Java and is running on Heroku. I do not want jars with test-scope in the production environment. One reason for this is the size of the Heroku-slug. So for example junit, selenium and green mail jars are currently in the target/dependency directory and I would prefer that they were not.

Is there something I can do with the pom or a maven option that would stop maven from putting test-scope jars in target/dependency?

I already have a couple of solutions that require that I maintain a second list of files not to include. But manually synching two lists have a tendency to fail sooner rather than later.

Comment: Test-scoped dependencies shouldn't be in the deployable asset anyway; how are you building your final artifact?

Comment: Using `maven-dependency-plugin` I presume. What for? Take a look at conf: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#includeScope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to add `<includeScope>compile</includeScope>` to your maven-dependency-plugin config:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The included scopes defaults to test, which includes your test dependencies, so compile will actually exclude them.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a way, where you can limit the scope of your dependency for test only.
just define the `scope` of every dependency you don't want in **prod** environment as given below with a `<scope></scope>` tag.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The question already indicates that there are jars/dependencies with test scope. So the only solution for an install is to use `<includeScope>` as mentioned by **codefinger**.